# Querying usb device by DeviceID with WQL

Tags: python, wmi, wql

I can get deviceID from WMI, then I want to use that deviceID to check weather device is in enabled\disabled state and if it's status is OK or not, basically I want to use WQL to query that device later on using this usb device unique DeviceID. Here is a code example that I used and got exception with

```
import wmi
devid = "USB\VID_04F2&PID_B315\6&EF94D1A&0&6"
c = wmi.WMI()
q2 = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID = " + devid + " "
dev = c.query(q2)
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1009, in query
>   return [ _wmi_object (obj, instance_of, fields) for obj in self._raw_query(wql) ]
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\util.py", line 84, in next return _get_good_object_(self.*iter*.next(), resultCLSID = self.resultCLSID)
>   pywintypes.com_error: (-2147217385, 'OLE error 0x80041017', None, None)

Probably my wql query is wrong somehow, could you give me an example of the right way the compose the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is a [special character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394054(v=vs.85).aspx) in WQL and must be escaped with a backslash so your `devid` should be this:

```
devid = "'USB\\VID_04F2&PID_B315\\6&EF94D1A&0&6'"
```

Edit: I also noticed that you aren't wrapping the constant so I added a single quote around the value.

Comment: do you have idea about how to transform string from '\' to '\\'?

Comment: If you are using an old version of Python, the easy way is with the `Replace` method, but you really should learn `Regex` https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html because it is integral to Python string manipulation. (Pay special attention to the `.Sub` function)